# Can I change the activity label from within my activity?

Tags: android

I have an activity which is going to switch around between several views, and in each view I would like the activity label to change. Is this possible? This is my manifest file.

```
   <activity android:name=".MiscParamsTwo"
        android:label="@string/misc_parameters2" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I would like to change the "@string/misc_parameters2" every time I switch views. I am doing this through the android menu.

```
case R.id.item3:
        // Anti-Pump
        setContentView( R.layout.antipump_phaserotation );
        return true;
    case R.id.item4:
        // Relaxed Close
        setContentView( R.layout.relaxed_close );
        return true;
    case R.id.item5:
        // Misc Parameters 1
        setContentView( R.layout.misc_params_one );
        return true;
    case R.id.item6:
        setContentView( R.layout.misc_params_two );
        // Misc Parameters 2
        return true;
    case R.id.item7:
        setContentView( R.layout.dnp_three );
        // DNP3 Setup
        return true;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just call

```
setTitle("New title");
```

or if you have a string declared in your strings.xml file

```
setTitle(R.string.title_resource_string);
```